# java : Why the thread priority is not followed when there are more than one print statements in run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

The file I'm executing:

```
class TestMultiPriority1 extends Thread{
public void run(){
System.out.println("running thread name is:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
System.out.println("running thread priority is:"+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());

}
public static void main(String args[]){
TestMultiPriority1 m1=new TestMultiPriority1();
TestMultiPriority1 m2=new TestMultiPriority1();
m1.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
m2.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
m1.start();``
m2.start();


}
}
```

The output iam getting for this code is:

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:1
running thread priority is:10
```

Whereas the output expected is

```
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:10
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread priority is:1
```

I mean the thread with the highest priority should get executed first completely then the second thread should be taken, isn't it?Has it got something to do with schedular?

Comment: The priority is a hint, the OS is free to ignore. If it doesn't ignore it, it will only matter when you have close to 100% CPU utilisation e.g. if you have free CPU even the lowest priority task can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Priority" may not mean what you think it means.

If the *absolute scheduler priority* of thread A is higher than the absolute scheduler priority of thread B, that does not necessarily prevent thread B from running.  The only time it matters is if, at any instant, there are more threads that want to use CPU cycles than there are CPUs for the threads to run on, then thread B will not be allowed to run if thread A is not running.

Thread B can run if Thread A is running on some *other* CPU, and Thread B can run if thread A is *waiting* for something (e.g., like waiting for a `System.out.println(...)` to complete).

---

But, in Java you can't even control the absolute scheduler priority.

Most desktop and server operating systems are designed to host multiple, independent apps that compete for CPU time.  The OS scheduler usually strives to give each app a *fair share* of CPU, and there's usually a parameter (called "nice" in UNIX/Linux) that allows you to adjust how large a process or thread's share is relative to other processes and threads.

That "nice" parameter is what a Java thread's "priority" actually controls.  So when you give one thread a higher "priority" than another, you're really only giving it a bigger share.  The other thread doesn't get *no* share, it just gets a smaller share.

---

Your demo program probably uses so little CPU time, that none of this matters anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't guarantee strict priority in any conditions. Look at [Java Language Specification (2nd Edition) p.445](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&pg=PA445&lpg=PA445&dq=Java%20Language%20Specification%20thread%20priority&source=bl&ots=Sf3LciMdnC&sig=l9u1BfL_hZC0TyEcrC0eGJpwyxk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO7eHx1e3LAhVnwHIKHUJpAggQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Java%20Language%20Specification%20thread%20priority&f=false):

> Every thread has a priority. When there is competition for processing resources, threads with higher priority are generally executed in preference to threads with lower priority. Such preference is not, however, a guarantee that the highest priority thread will always be running, and thread priorities cannot be used to reliably implement mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Priority level is only hint. As a lot of stuff about multithreading in Java :P.